# Using a return value as a parameter in java

Tags: java, parameters, return

If I want to use the return value of Method A as a parameter for Method B in java, how exactly would I go about doing that? for example, Method A returns whether today was sunny or cloudy, and Method B finds the percent of days in the month that are sunny.

Comment: `myMethodA(myMethodB(today))` ? (Or the other way around, depending on which method does what exactly)

Comment: @hmjd: It should be `methodA` and `methodB` according to the java's conventions (and not `MethodA`,`MethodB`, using lower case for methods first char)

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way...

```
public void chkIt(doIt()){

   System.out.println(doIt());  // But then you will unnecessarily call it twice.

}


public boolean doIt(){


  return true;

}
```